# Sorted a list of directory in python

Tags: python, file, sorting, directory

I would like to sort a list of directory.

My code is :

```
Files = []
Files2 = []
for path in os.listdir(File_Prevent):
        Files.append(path)
Path = []
for i in range(0, len(Files)) :
    for path in os.listdir(File_Prevent + Files[i]) :       
        Files2.append(File_Prevent + Files[i] + '/' + path)
        Path.append(path)
        
Path = sorted(Path)
Files2 = sorted(Path)
```

The result is :

```
C:/Users/lucas/Desktop/Stage_S10/Partie_Code/Donnees_joueur/Donnees_prevent/
Donnees_par_impact/2021-09-04/MG44020-0021-2021-09-04T121703+975.csv
C:/Users/lucas/Desktop/Stage_S10/Partie_Code/Donnees_joueur/Donnees_prevent/
Donnees_par_impact/2021-09-05/MG43891-0002-2021-09-05T101845+946.csv
```

You can see that the document 'MG43891' is after 'MG44020'.

I would like to sort them, based on the name of the file.

I use the fonction 'sorted' but it dosen't work with my data.

Do you have an other way to sort it ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please post the code, an example of the input (the `dict`), and how the output differs from what you desire.

Comment: Therefore, you want to sort files not directories, based on the date inside each file name. Lastly, what is the date in the file `MG44020-0021-2021-09-04T121703+975.csv` ?

Comment: They have the same date because I download them at the same time.

Comment: Oops, I read "directory" as "dictionary." Thanks for the details.

Comment: Therefore, you care only about the final digits, in your example: `+975`

Comment: Wait, do you care about the final digits (`+975`) or the first part of the filename (`MG44020`)?

Answer (score 0):

Getting all files in directory with glob:

```
filepaths = glob.glob(r"path\to\folder\*.csv")
```

For each string representing a path, use regex to extract substring with datetime:

```
filepaths = [tuple([filepath, re.findall("\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{6}\+\d{3}", filepath)[0]]) for filepath in filepaths]
```

Transforming, for each tuple, the string to datetime:

```
filepaths = [tuple([x[0], dt.datetime.strptime(x[1], "%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%S+%f")]) for x in filepaths]
```

Sorting based on datetime element:

```
filepaths = sorted(filepaths, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Sorted:

```
print([x[0] for x in filepaths])
```